# ionic android platform error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

When I added android platform to my ionic project I get this error.Can someone please tell whats wrong here.my node js version is 4.4.3

```
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'config-chain'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\UVINDU\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:2:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

Comment: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/656 look this

Comment: Are you using macos?

Comment: no im not using macos its windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following these steps fixed the problem for me
http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/